# Calling Entity Framework models from inside DBMigration Up()

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

We are using Entity Framework Code-First. One of our old databases needs multiple migrations applied, but on (say) 3 of 7, the migration fails with

**ERROR: The model backing the 'MyContext' context has changed since the database was created.**

The same migration worked fine for our other databases, but those dbs were updated as the migrations came out - i.e. one migration at a time.

The DBMigration Up() method for that migration uses some of our EF model classes to do some data changes, so I think the issue is that the code for our models expect migration 7 to be there.

Are there any strategies to avoid this effect, other than moving all EF calls from the Up()/Down() to the Seed() method (which loses the link to what migration it is applicable to)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a migration is scaffolded for you, it has no calls against your model and that is intentionally so.  If you used your own models in an Up() in an early migration and then decided you didn't need those models anymore that migration would be pooched.

You are correct in thinking that the Seed method is built specifically to handle adding relevant data like universal lookups, etc.  If you were to remove a lookup table all together, you'd simply just remove that seeding logic that no longer is required.

Basically, it's an intentional separation of concerns that migrations shouldn't have a direct tie to any EF models directly.

Answer (score 0):

Adding an alternative answer to my own question that a colleague suggested; using ADO.net calls instead of EF calls within the Up/Down methods. This lets the data be changed up or down with that migration, as opposed to the seed method (which doesn't really know if it is going up of down on that migration change).

Still, i think Runesun answered the 'why' of the question better, so marked that correct.